# How to create dynamic table in sqlite-3 using python when user give your email address

Tags: python, sqlite, dynamic

Sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ℅s (℅s text, ℅s text)" ℅ (Username, "first", " Second ")
con. execute(sql)

#Error- sqlite3.OperationError:near "@gmail": syntax error

#help me sir

Comment: Table name should be username.

Comment: You shouldn't be using string substitution for your SQL ...

Answer (score 0):

Though I must admit that it seems strange to me to create tables with data-depending names, but technically the solution is to put the table name in square parentheses. This is the way to escape special characters like '@'.

Something like this:

```
Sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [℅s] (℅s text, ℅s text)" ℅ (Username, "first", " Second ")
```

Comment: dear sir, after run this program gives an error is:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting